# Change retURL for ChangePassword page

Tags: community, passwords

When users click to reset their password and go through the process through the link that gets sent in an email, there's a variable **retURL** that seems to be the url to redirect to once the password is successfully reset. I have been unable to find anywhere in the admin or anywhere in the template/controllers/etc. where this retURL value is specified. The page that's being used for resetting the password is just the default reset password page. Any ideas of where this value can be found and replaced would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to create your own VF page + controller, and assign that page to the community `Change Password` page. Then put a custom redirect inside your custom controller...

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround I found for this was to use the standard `ChangePassword` template page, style it up obviously, and then change the controller (`ChangePasswordController`) default `changePassword` method to redirect to the intended destination:

```
public PageReference changePassword() {
    // This is the original code
    // return Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);    
    // Changed it to the following:
    // Change the password, then explicitly login the user with the new password and redirect
    Site.changePassword(newPassword, verifyNewPassword, oldpassword);    
    return Site.Login(Userinfo.getUsername(), newPassword, '/newRedirectPath');
}
```

Then you could just set the default change password page to be a Visualforce page (`ChangePassword`), add the page to the Site Enabled VF Pages, and you're good to go.

Comment: Can we redirect to another page if we have already reset the password using the link?